# Remove shadow on iOS 7 UIPickerView

Tags: ios7, uipickerview, uipicker

On the bottom of my standard picker view, there is a purple shadow. Is there a way to remove that or at least change the color?
Thanks

Comment: What shadow? Could you show what you have?

Comment: i don't have enough rep to post a picture. i can email it to you

Comment: Add the link here I will upload it for you

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/957249#957249